# C++ | Dereference a member pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

Well, lets say that I have a `struct` or a `class` that has a lets say `int` pointer as one of its members, something like this:

```
struct /*or class*/ some_struct /*or class*/ {
    int *pointer = NULL;
} *obj_pointer;
```

and as the program goes `obj_pointer` and `obj_pointer->pointer` get initialized, how can I dereference `obj_pointer->pointer` so that I can print(`cout`) for example the value of the memory the pointer is pointing to?

Comment: but make sure to make the pointer point to something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like any other pointer, using the dereference operator `*`:

```
std::cout << *obj_pointer->pointer;
```

The member access operator `->` have higher [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the dereference operator `*`

Comment: I imagined it could be done like that,but when I tried it and I printed the values (I wanted that for double-linked list) I got some weird values, so I wanted to see if the dereference way was wrong or the way I was making my double-linked list